# Trigger on any column change except specific one

Tags: postgresql

I want to trigger on all column changes on a table except a specific one, but listing all the columns in the AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF clause is a problem because the table has many columns and the set of columns changes at times, making maintaining the trigger definition in sync very error prone. How can I do this in a way that I just specify the column to omit from the trigger? For the moment I have an event trigger that prints a warning to update the trigger when that table is altered, but that relies on the user noticing the warning and obviously won't help when creating a new db.

Comment: Have your trigger function return early if `new.column = old.column`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek, I believe @Display Name is referring to `UPDATE OF column_name1 [, column_name2 ... ]` . In other words the list of columns that the trigger will respond to, not the change in column values

Comment: I don't know of a way to make the trigger definition dynamic. The only idea I can come up with is write the column changes to a table and inside the trigger function do a look up and ignore those columns. Though this means the trigger will fire on all updates.   Actually a second idea would be to maintain change scripts that modified the table columns and the trigger definition at the same time.